# Parceljs configuration

Tags: web, frontend, bundler, parceljs

I have a problem with import html-files in index.html.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "author": "test",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/pages/index.html"
  }
}
```

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwNIM.png)

I tried include header.html in index.html like this, but it's didn't work.
`<include src="src/pages/templates/header.html"></include>`

How can i include html files on index.html page?

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin: https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-modules.

It may require the following `.posthtmlrc` file in your project root (assuming an `src` folder):

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "posthtml-modules": {
      "root": "src"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between posthtml-modules and posthtml-include?

Answer (score 1):

The `.posthtmlrc` didn't seem to do anything for me.

Here's how I did it:

Install `posthtml-include`: `npm i posthtml-include --save-dev`

Create a file called `posthtml.config.js` in the top level of your Parcel project:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('posthtml-include')({
      root: `${__dirname}/partials` // "partials" can be renamed
    })
  ]
};
```

Then create a `./partials` folder with an HTML file inside. To include it use this syntax:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<include src="test.html"></include>
```